# Wordpress cannot get_current_user_id() from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I try to do an ajax request with wordpress. So I've created a simple js request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'pr_post': post,
        'pr_rating': rating
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Here is my function to handle the request.

```
function pr_request()
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['pr_post']) && isset($_REQUEST['pr_rating']) && isset($_REQUEST['pr_user'])) {

         $post = $_REQUEST['pr_post'];
         $rating = ($_REQUEST['pr_rating'] > 5 ? 5 : $_REQUEST['pr_rating']);
         $user = get_current_user_id();

         if (!pr_has_user_already_voted($user, $post)) {

             global $wpdb;
             $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'mitmach_ratings';

             $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("insert into $table values (null, $post, $rating, '$user');"));
             wp_send_json(['message' => 'success']);

         } else {
             wp_send_json(['message' => 'duplicate'], 403);
         }
    }
 }
```

As you see I call the `get_current_user_id()` function. This function always returns true even if the user logged in. How can I get the user id in my handler without sending it via ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start check docs - [WP Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

You need to send `action` key

> Notice how the 'action' key's value 'my_action', defined in our JavaScript above, matches the latter half of the action 'wp_ajax_my_action' in our AJAX handler below. This is because it is used to call the server side PHP function through admin-ajax.php. If an action is not specified, admin-ajax.php will exit, and return 0 in the process.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action    : 'pr_post',
        pr_rating : rating
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
     }
});
```

and call like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pr_request', 'pr_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pr_request', 'pr_request' );

function pr_request() {
  // Code
}
```

Comment: I've added the `add_action` function to my plugin registry. Now I get the page content instend of my json result defined with `wp_send_json`. The logic from the pr_request function won't be executed too.

Comment: Can you show us the ```pr_request()``` function code?

Comment: ```$_REQUEST['pr_post']``` does not exist now, but this if statement is unnecessary.  This function cant be called except through ajax request with action **pr_request**.

Comment: Oh yes. My mistake. Sorry and thank you. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action    : 'pr_request',
            pr_rating : rating
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
         }
    });
```

Using [@sky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2245806/sky)'s answer, I found in the [WP AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) docs that the url should be the global WP `ajaxurl` variable instead.

Hoping this helps someone else...